# Implementation of Dekker's algoirthm with atomic

Tags: c++, c++11, memory

I am reading about C++ memory model how these are applied. 
I really confused when the  sequentially consistent model is necessary instead of the acquire-release model.
For example let's examine the Dekker's algorithm
Reading the following tutorial https://www.think-cell.com/en/career/talks/pdf/think-cell_talk_memorymodel.pdf , it is recommended to use sequentially consistent model for the Dekker's algorithm.

Have a look in the following example

```
atomic<bool> f1=false;
atomic<bool> f2=false;

//thread 1
f1.store(true, memory_order_seq_cst);
if (!f2.load(memory_order_seq_cst)) {
// critical section
}
f1.store(false);

//thread 2
f2.store(true, memory_order_seq_cst);
if (!f1.load(memory_order_seq_cst)) {
// critical section
}
f2.store(false);
```

Why the release-acquire model in this case cannot quarantee that store and load operations take place without any reordering?

Thank you
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory operations here indeed take place without reordering inside a single thread. But, there is no guarantee between threads. To achieve the desired behavior you have to use [atomic compare exchange](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange) functions.